# wordpress becomes irresponsive when plugin is run

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

i've created a woocommerce plugin,
the plugin itself runs perfectly.
However as long as it takes for it to run, i'm experiencing wierd performances issues.
The website is totally inaccessible(both frontend and backend) ONLY from the browser that is logged in and ran the plugin.
Both frontend and backend are loading until the plugin finishes.
to make things even wierder it's working perfectly from another browser.

also this is run on a high-end dedicated server and when it's running the loads on the server are very low.

any clues?

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php');

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
$woocommerce = new Client(woocommerce_api_url, api_key, api_secret,['version' => 'wc/v3','timeout' => '99999',]);
echo '<pre>';
$db = new DBfdr();
$i=0;
$page = 1;
$products = [];
$all_products = [];
do{
  try {
    $products = $woocommerce->get('products',array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => $page));
  } catch(HttpClientException $e) {
    die("Can't get products: $e");
  }
  $all_products = array_merge($all_products,$products);
  $page++;
```

Notes: the DBfdr class contains a simple function for managing pdo connections to the sql server.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but that code looks quite inefficient; is it possible to combine both queries into a single query?

Comment: _“ONLY from the browser that is logged in”_ - then it is probably a manifestation of the quite common problem of the session data file being _locked_; while your script is still using the session, all other scripts trying to access that same session, will have to wait. Normally the solution is to call `session_write_close` as soon as possible, but with an actual WordPress plugin, I can’t tell you whether that would be a good idea. If WP needs to do additional stuff with the session after your code has run, that might fail.

Comment: @Ken i have removed part of the code. As you can see it only connects to the WC API and gets all products. same issue here.

Comment: @CBroe If i understand what you mean correctly, i could host the script outside of wordpress installation and just call it from the wordpress backend. do you believe that it will work?

Comment: That will depend on what exactly _“just call it from the wordpress backend”_ means, I guess. You will need to load part of the WP functionality, for the WooCommerce stuff to work - and that likely requires a working session to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That piece of code doesn't look so good, why would you need to make a plugin that externally loads wp then going through Woocommerce Client Api to get the list of products and then cycle all of them to make an if condition.

That would be so much more efficient if you would just pass inside WP standard plugin structure, using global $wpdb class and performing your queries with some join.

That said, the problem you are facing could be solved by adding this before your code:

```
ignore_user_abort( true );
        
/* Don't make the request block till we finish, if possible. */
if ( function_exists( 'fastcgi_finish_request' ) && version_compare( phpversion(), '7.0.16', '>=' ) ) {
    fastcgi_finish_request();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this answer. I have tried this solution but unfortunately when fastcgi_finish_request() is ran it also stops the execution of the rest of the code.

Comment: Mmm, what should happen is that the page seems like stopping, but the underlying code should keep executing. Try to log what the code does inside a file, you should see it writing even after you feel like the code stopped

Answer (score 0):

The problems occurs because the wp-config.php is included in the beggining.

wp-config.php in the end has

```php
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

which inits some core wordpress functions which in turn "locks" the session.
i managed to fix the issue by removing

```php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php');
```

and replacing it with customs defines